# Javascript showing tr when the list item has a specific value

Tags: javascript

I've to following question. I've a multiple listitem and i want show the three hidden tr i've set to display 'hidden' when the list item has a specific value.

the form elements have the following set up

```
<tr>
<td><label>bla</label></td>
<td><input id='bla'></td>
</tr>
```

i use the following javascript.

```
function checkValue(){

var verhuurdVan = document.getElementById('verhuurd_van_datepicker_field').parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';
var verhuurdTot = document.getElementById('verhuurd_tot_datepicker_field').parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';
var beschikbaar = document.getElementById('beschikbaar_verhuur_1').parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none'; 

var list = document.getElementById('productstatus_id_ListOn');

for(var i=0; i<list.options.length; i++){ 
    if(list.options[i].value == '1'){
      here the table rows has to be set to display block; 
    }
}
```

Ignore the HTML id name's because this is parsed by the CMS i use.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to show one of three hidden rows, based on selection of one of three options in the list?

Comment: I want to show all of the three rows when the value in the list is equals to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the exact layout of your DOM it's not possible to give the exact lines of code required.  However, it seems quite clear from the code block you posted that the elements are being hidden by lines 3-5.

Consequently, within your inner `if` block, all you have to do to make the elements reappear is to set the style of the corresponding elements back to 'block', e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('verhuurd_tot_datepicker_field').parentNode.parentNode.style.display='block';
```

Which of the three nodes you actually activate is up to you to decide, but that's *how* you would go about it.

Comment: That seems to be a table row, and setting the display style of a row to `block` is a bad idea. Better set it to an empty string, so that it takes its default display style.

Comment: Thank you very much it works fine. Kinda stupid question if i see the results by now. But i thought about the var. I thought the following may work also. 

Udate:
@verhuurdVan yes i noticed that also i set it now to style.display=''. 
verhuurdVan.style.display = 'block';